# What algorithm spark uses to bring same keys together

Tags: apache-spark

What algorithm Spark uses to identify similar keys and pushes the data to the next stage?

Scenarios include,

1. When I apply distinct(), I know a pre-distinct applied in the current stage and then the data is shuffled to the next stage. In this case, all the similar keys need to be in the same partition in the next stage.
2. When Dataset1 joins with Dataset2 (SortMergeJoin). In this case, all the similar keys in Dataset1 and Dataset2 needs to be in the same partition in next stage.

There are other scenarios as well, but overall picture is this.

How does Spark efficiently does this? and will there be any time lag between Stage1 and Stage2 when identifying the similar keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm Spark uses to partition the data is Hash by default. Also stages don't push but pull the data from previous stage.

Spark creates a stage boundaries whenever a shuffle is needed. Second stage will wait untill all the tasks in stage first complete and write their output to temp files. Second stage then starts pulling the data needed for its partitions from across the partitions written in stage 1.
Distinct as you see isn't as simple as it looks. Spark does distinct by applying aggregates. Also shuffling is needed because duplicates can be in multiple partitions. One of the conditions for shuffling is Spark needs a pair RDD and if your parent isn't one, it will create intermediary pair RDDs.
If you see the logical plan of Distinct, it would be more or less like
Parent RDD ---> Mapped RDD (record as key and null values) ---> MapPartitionsRDD (running distinct at partition level) ----> Shuffled RDD (pulling needed partitions data) ----> MapPartitionsRDD (distinct from segregated partitions for each key) ----> Mapped RDD (collecting only keys and discarding null values for result)

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses RDD Dependency to achieve that  data is shuffled to the next stage. And know which is a complexed processes;
The getDependencies function in RDD.SCALA is responsible to get the data from parent.

```
    /**
   * Implemented by subclasses to return how this RDD depends on parent RDDs. This method will only
   * be called once, so it is safe to implement a time-consuming computation in it.
   */
  protected def getDependencies: Seq[Dependency[_]] = deps
```

And Some RDD dont have to get parent rdd, so the rdd dont implement the function **compute**,like DataSource RDD;

[image: DataSourceRDD Stucture]
Shuffle rowRDD usually appear in chain compute, so it usually have the parent data to fetch.
[image: ShuffledROwRDD with implemention of compute]